# packaging multiple report in an addon on sap business one

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

I have developed 15 reports on crystal report for sap business one and I would like to compress my solution in an addon on SAP Business One.

Should I go through the SAP Business One SDK? or there is another solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think, You should give more informations about what your addon is doing..

If You only want to deploy reports, the best choice is to use the Layout and Raport Manager import wizard (b1px,b1p,rpt files are allowed).

But if You need more complex functionality in your addon, You should use the Crystal Reports Developer for Visual Studio.

For example, I'm using them to dynamically generate multiple PDF documents from my addon solution.

To do this, im using following references:

`CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
CrystalDecisions.Shared`

Best regards